# How to determine correct linker order for a c++ project in cdt eclipse?

Tags: c++, linker-errors, eclipse-cdt

I dont want to randomly place libraries in arbitrary order hoping I get the order correct. Is there a systematic way to determine the linker library order in eclipse cdt?

ERROR: cannot find -l{some project}

Comment: I did not undertand what you mean by library order? Did you get any linker error? Paste it here please.

Comment: /bin/ld: cannot find -l{some project}

Comment: There is no such thing called order. If you have a function or class implementation twice, compilation fails.

Comment: in c++, libraries have to be linked in the order that its called.. I just wanted to know how you determine what order to enter the libraries into the Linker in eclipse

Comment: @ElvisTeixeira I added the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct saying that `-l` directives must follow a certain order. However, this error means a different thing. The linker simply failed to find the library file you have specified. Perhaps, you're missing the `-L` directive which specifies the folder where the linker looks for the library files. E. g.

> -L../bin -l{libname}

Answer (score 0):

Ok as long as you got "can not find -lsomething. You should put libsomething.so (or.dll or .a etc, the library) in a directory of your choice and the tell the compiler to look at this directory with compiler flag

```
  -L/path/to/libsomething
```

Note that the -L flag tell the compiler where to look for libraries and the -l (lowercase) tell it to actaly link the library, so you must provide a path to the former and a library name to the later.